# Не работает копирование в буфер обмена, доработка регулярок

Tags: javascript, html, регулярные-выражения

Эта программа приводит разметку из такого вида:

```
<ul>
< li>цвет: синий< / li>
< li > Материал: ПВХ< / li>
< li>Размер: 80 * 40см < / li>
< li>вес: 123 г< / li>
</ul>
```

В такой вид:

```
<ul>
<li>цвет: синий</li>
<li> Материал: ПВХ</li>
<li>Размер: 80 * 40см </li>
<li>вес: 123 г</li>
</ul>
```

Вопросы:

1. Как доработать, чтобы справа от `>` в открывающем теге и слева от `<` в закрывающем, не было пробелов.
2. Нужно, чтобы первая буква после `>` становилась прописной, если не прописная.
3. Раньше по клику на кнопку Copy всё копировалось в буфер, теперь не работает. Как вернуть?

```js
'use strict'
const inp = document.querySelector('#input');
const out = document.querySelector('#output');
const btn = document.querySelector('#fix');
const writeBtn = document.querySelector('#copy');
let pre_content = '';

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const text = inp.value;
  output.innerText = text.replace(/<\s*(\/)?\s*([^>\s]+)\s*(\s[^>]*)?>/g, '<$1$2$3>');
  pre_content = output.textContent; 
});
writeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(pre_content)
});
```

```css
button {
    background: #22c1c3;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 45px
}
```

```html
<button id="copy">Copy</button>
<hr/>
<textarea id="input" cols="75%" rows="10"></textarea>
<pre id=output></pre>
<hr/>
<button id="fix">Fix</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для предотвращения удаления пробелов вокруг обратного слеша в тексте между тегами, рекомендуется замена в два прохода (да и регулярки понятнее и проще):

```js
'use strict'
const inp = document.querySelector('#input');
const out = document.querySelector('#output');
const btn = document.querySelector('#fix');
const writeBtn = document.querySelector('#copy');
let pre_content = ``;

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let text = inp.value;
  // Удаляем лишние пробелы
  text = text.replace(/\u0020*([<>])\u0020*/g, '$1').replace(/\u0020*((?:<)\/)\u0020*/g, '$1');
  // Делаем первую букву содержимого тегов заглавной
  text = text.replace(/>(.)(.+)</g, function(match, p1, p2) {
    return `>${p1.toUpperCase()}${p2}<`;
  });

  output.innerText = text;

  pre_content = output.textContent;
});
writeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(pre_content);
});
```

```css
button { height: 45px; width: 150px; border: none; border-radius: 25px; background: #22c1c3; }
```

```html
<button id="copy">Copy</button>
<hr/>
<textarea id="input" cols="75%" rows="10"><ul>
< li>цвет: синий< / li>
< li > Материал: ПВХ< / li>
< li>Размер: 80 * 40см < / li>
< li>вес: 123 г< / li>
</ul></textarea>
<pre id=output></pre>
<hr/>
<button id="fix">Fix</button>
```

Comment: А по поводу большой первой буквы и копирования в буфер можете что-то подсказать?

Comment: @BlackFire: добавил.

Comment: Да, работает) Только в буфер не копируется, хотя не знаю, что может мешать.

Comment: @BlackFire: похоже, что проблема в этом - https://goo.gl/EuHzyv

Comment: Да, Chromium подставил. Но в firefox работает.